# Google Identity Toolkit ignores hash (#) fragment of signInSuccessUrl

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I'm using Google Identity Toolkit for authentication in my web application (GAE for Java). When the user tries to access the URL `http://www.example.com/home#xyz`, my application redirects the user to the authentication page, which in my case is `http://www.example.com/oauth2callback?mode=select&signInSuccessUrl=/home#xyz`.

However, after successful authentication, identity toolkit redirects the user to `http://www.example.com/home` instead of `http://www.example.com/home#xyz`.

Is this an issue with the identity toolkit or am I missing something? Is there a workaround to retain the hash fragment after the redirect?

Here's the complete use case.

User goes to URL `http://www.example.com/home#xyz`. If the user is not signed-in, the `home` page, which is a JSP redirects the user to `http://www.example.com/oauth2callback?mode=select&signInSuccessUrl=/home` using a scriptlet.

JSP scriptlet doesn't have access to the hash fragment `#xyz` (because it's running in the server) but the browser automatically appends `#xyz` at the end and I see `http://www.example.com/oauth2callback?mode=select&signInSuccessUrl=/home#xyz` in the address bar.

However, after sign-in, user is redirected to `http://www.example.com/home`. I need to get access to the hash fragment in my JSP scriptlet, which I'm not sure how to do, so that I can encode the URI with the hash fragment as mentioned in bojeil's response below.

Comment: According to OAuth2 spec, the redirect URL should not include fragment(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2). The workaround is to put that xyz in context(https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/createAuthUri#http-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget url should be:
`'http://www.example.com/oauth2callback?mode=select&signInSuccessUrl=' + encodeURIComponent('/home#xyz')`

The hash part is being treated as part of the url itself and the signInSuccessUrl query value here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a challenge in implementing your approach. See the 'UPDATE' I added to my OP.

Comment: Coincidentally, exactly one year later, I happened to test it again and your approach works! Thank you.